# Payload not getting updated by method in setter

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, html, lwc-dom

Trying to write a getter and setter method to simply update my `JSON` payload to have `name.first` ***be the student's first and last name*** so that way the `lightning-button` can show as their full name, this would be at `studnet.name.first` on the `html`.

I am able to view the data how it comes as of now, so name comes through for the students but I am struggling to figure out what am I missing here. I am unable to update the payload and unable to see after the for loop `alert()s` when I have them in my `setStudentName()` method. I am guessing that the setter hits the method but then fails and then kicks it out of it.

**HTML:**

```
<template>
    <template for:each={outputResult.classes} for:item="classRecord">
        <div key={classRecord.classNumber}>
            <lightning-accordion>
                <lightning-accordion-section label={classRecord.classNumber}>
                    <template for:each={classRecord.classList} for:item="student">
                        <div key={student.id}>
                            <lightning-button variant="base" label={student.name.first}>
                            </lightning-button>
                            <div>{student.phone.number}|{student.email}</div>
                            <lightning-accordion for:each={student.extraActivites} for:item="activity" key={activity.id}>
                                <lightning-accordion-section label="Involved Activities">
                                    <div>{activity.name.activityName}</div>
                                </lightning-accordion-section>
                            </lightning-accordion>
                        </div>
                    </template>
                </lightning-accordion-section>
            </lightning-accordion>
        </div>
    </template>
</template>
```

**JS:**

```
import { LightningElement, api } from 'lwc';
import retrieveResultOutput from '@salesforce/apex/studentViewer.retrieveResultOutput';
export default class StudentViewer extends LightningElement{
         resultRecords;
    
         @api get resultOutput(){
              return this.resultRecords;
         }
    
         set resultOuput(records) {
              this.resultRecords = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(records));
              this.setStudentName;
         }
    
         setStudentName(){
              for(let record of this.resultRecords){
              let first = record.name.first;
              let last = record.name.last;
              record.name.first = `${first} ${last}`;
              }
         }
    
         async connectedCallback(){
              let requestPayload ='{"data":"requested"}'
              this.resultOuput = await retrieveResultOutput({parameter:requestPayload})
         }
    }
```

**JSON:**

```
{
  "classes": [
    {
      "classNumber": 1,
      "classList": [
        {
          "name": {
            "first": "tristan",
            "last": "berger"
          },
          "id": 1,
          "email": "email@gmail.com",
          "phone": {
            "number": "1112223456"
          },
          "extraActivites": [
            {
              "activityId": 1,
              "name": {
                "activityName": "baking"
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": {
            "first": "eric",
            "last": "cartman"
          },
          "id": 2,
          "email": "email2@gmail.com",
          "phone": {
            "number": "1112223457"
          },
          "extraActivites": [
            {
              "activityId": 2,
              "name": {
                "activityName": "running"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "classNumber": 2,
      "classList": [
        {
          "name": {
            "first": "john",
            "last": "doe"
          },
          "id": 3,
          "email": "email3@gmail.com",
          "phone": {
            "number": "1112223477"
          },
          "extraActivites": [
            {
              "activityId": 2,
              "name": {
                "activityName": "baking"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to fix the method being called inside the setter. Was not targeting correct object in the array originally.

```
     setStudentName(){
          for(let record of this.resultRecords.classes){
               for(let student of record.classList){
                    let first = student .name.first;
                    let last = student .name.last;
                    student .name.first = `${first} ${last}`;
               }
          }
     }
```